# Localizing UIWebView with stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error: in XCode 4?

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4, localization

I'm trying to load up a localized html into an UIWebView. All resources I find on google are for the old XCode versions, using en.proj XX.proj Folders in the main Folder.

For localizing my about.htm I go to the "Identity and Type">"Localization" window and add the localisations to about.htm. On the file system this creates the XX.proj Folders, but in XCode 4 it shows as

```
> about.htm
  about.htm (English)
  about.htm (German)
```

I senn fill the about.htm (German) wiff se German html.

I use one AboutViewController.xib, with one UIWebView and load up as follows:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSString* html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"about" ofType:@"htm"]
                                           encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                              error:nil];
[aboutUIWebView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:baseURL];
/*
// this one doesn't show the css images
NSString *indexPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"about" 
                                                      ofType:@"htm" 
                                                 inDirectory:nil];
[aboutUIWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest 
             requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:indexPath]]];
*/
```

This correctly shows the English, but never the German. Even though the rest of the app shows in German, the UIWebView refuses to show the German. A "Reset Content and Settings.." and clean run on the simulator does not help either.

What am I missing? What can be done? 
Thank you

Comment: You're definitely doing something else wrong - that code is fine.

Comment: I restarted XCode and did another hard reset on the Simulator and now it loads up, however, on the device (iPod4touch,ios5.1) it does not, and I can hardly ask users to hard reset their devices so that my UIView loads their language? Any other ideas?

Comment: When I change the english, it has no effect actually either. Must be somehow stuck inside the app/cash/webview somewhere... maybe need to force load from bundle?

Comment: Remove the app then reinstall it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try manually inspecting the folder Xcode creates (in `/Users/<username>/Library/Application support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/<ID>/<applicationName>.app/`). Make sure that the directory structure is as you expected and fix it if it's not.

Comment: As this is the only answer I give the credit to Tom van der Woerdt. The solution indeed was to delete the app, and re-install it. I can only recommend developers to localize ALL of the resources that need localization before the first deploy.